# How can remove special character in php?

Tags: php, string

**In php, If I have**

```
$ABC = "love";
echo $abc;
-----
Display: love
```

**That's so okay. BUT if I have**

```
$ABC = "$love"; //Have $ in the string.
echo $abc;
-----
Display: Unkown variable love
```

I want:

```
$ABC = "$love"; //Have $ in the string.
echo $abc;
-----
Display: $love //$love are all text character
```

How can I change `$` become character, It will not be `$` as the variable. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\` to escape it, or just use single quote.

```
$ABC = "\$love";
// or
$ABC = '$love';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$la='$love';
echo $la;
echo '<br>';
$lb="\$lover";
echo $lb;
?>
```

outputs 
$love
$lover

Learn the differences between single and double quotes when defining a string.!

Comment: I think that I use \ to escape is perfect way.